# What is the name of the Force invisible creature?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

In *[Darth Maul: Shadow Hunter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darth+Maul%3A_Shadow_Hunter?wprov=sfla1)* a beast is mentioned that is living on Coruscant, underground, that could be used to create a cloak of Force invisibility.

> Lorn, unaware of this, uses a piece from the body of a subterranean creature to block his presence in the Force, and follows Maul to a Republic space station.

What is the name of that creature? Does it appear in any other book?

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Taozin?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## The creature you're looking for is a [Taozin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Taozin)

> Finding their way all over the galaxy, taozin were thought to be extinct until Darsha Assant, Lorn Pavan, and I-5YQ stumbled across one circa 32 BBY while fleeing from Darth Maul in the depths of the Coruscant underworld.
> <sub>[Star Wars Wikia - Taozin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Taozin)</sub>

The creature made its first appearance in Darth Maul: Shadow Hunter, followed by mentions in both [Coruscant Nights II: Street of Shadows](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Coruscant_Nights_II:_Street_of_Shadows) in August 2008 and [Coruscant Nights III: Patterns of Force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Coruscant_Nights_III:_Patterns_of_Force) in January 2009. It's next appearance  in [Darth Plagueis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Plagueis_(novel)) published in January 2012. It's most recent appearance was in [The Last Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Last_Jedi_(novel)) (not the film) in February 2013.

Unfortunately the only sources I can currently give you are from the wiki, I will update them with Legends sources later. <sub>(If I can acquire said sources)</sub>